# Tracing raster map on QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am not yet used to QGIS (I often get lost in menus for simple things), and I would like to make shapefiles using historical maps. Here is an example: (the real map is in higher resolution).

[image: Example map]

I would like to put it in QGIS, align it to the actual geographical map, and use it to trace some of the elements and export it into a shapefile.

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: @IanTurton I have only tried uploading the jpeg file as a raster layer (which didn't really work), I have no idea what else to attempt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The workflow that you can follow to get the desired output is as follows:-

1. Georeference the Map [Georefrencing in QGIS](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html#:%7E:text=Georeferencing%20in%20QGIS%20is%20done,plugin%20in%20the%20Installed%20tab.)
2. Once the map is georeferenced, create new shapefiles(Points, Lines, and Polygons)
3. Digitize the features that you might want to get from the map

Kindly follow the lessons below for a better understanding.

[Lesson: Georeferencing a Map](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html)

[Lesson: Digitizing](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/stands_digitazing.html)

Comment: Lesson links as of today: [Georeferencing a map](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/map_georeferencing.html) & [Digitizing forest stands](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/forestry/stands_digitazing.html).

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to the solution of Yogesh Chavan, I'd like to add a suggestion regarding georeferencing old maps. They are often rather imperfect and generally without any coordinates, therefore, I often found it easier to use the plugin Freehand Raster Georeferencer (available in the plugin menu or here: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FreehandRasterGeoreferencer/).

The plugin isn't perfect but works well. It allows placing old maps more intuitively, similar to the workflow in Google Earth. Remember to "export" (as geotiff or equivalent) after you've placed the image.